# Searching Muiltple arrays for keywords Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm a very amateur java coder trying to create a chat bot for a Uni assignment. I want the program to search through my animal arrays and if a keyword is found i can use the name of the array to give a certain response. I have two problems so far(i imagine a lot more to come).

The first- My matching system will only recognize the keyword if its the only word entered into the inputdialog. For example, i can only say "dog", or "dogs", but id like to say "I want to talk about dogs" and it will find the keyword in the sentence.

The second problem if the keyword isn't found in the first array, why doesn't move the next array ?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Chatbot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String animal1[] = {"Dogs","Dawgs","dogs"};
    String animal2[] = {"Cats"};
    String animal3[] = {"Horses"};
    String animal4[] = {"Lamas"};
    String animal5[] = {"Ducks"};
    String animal6[] = {"Pigs"};
    String animal7[] = {"Cows"};
    String animal8[] = {"Rabbits"};
    String animal9[] = {"Chickens"};
    String animal10[] = {"Mice"};


  String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hi there, theses are all the animals i like to talk about ! :"
                + "\n-Dogs"
                +"\n-Cats"
                +"\n-Rabbits"
                +"\n-Lamas"
                +"\n-Hores"
                +"\n-Ducks"
                +"\n-Pigs"
                +"\n-Cows"
                +"\n-Chickens"
                +"\n-Mice"
                +"\n-Ask me somthing !");       

  int  i;
  boolean found=false; {

  }

 //DOGS
  for(i=0; i<animal1.length;i++){
      found=true;
        // match your regex containing words from array against input
      if(response.matches(".*\\b"+animal1[i]+"\\b.*")){
  String dog = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Dogs ? I love dogs, they taste great!\n" + "What other animals do you like ?");
  //CATS
      }
  else
      for(i=0; i<animal2.length;i++){
          found=true;
      if(response.matches(".*\\b"+animal2[i]+"\\b.*")){
  String cat = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cats ? I love cats, they taste great!\n" + "What other animals do you like ?");

      }
else
  if(response.matches(".*\\b"+animal3[i]+"\\b.*")){
String horse = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Horses ? I love Horses, they taste great!\n" + "What other animals do you like ?");

  }     
   }        
    } 
     } 
    }
```

Comment: `String#contains` will help you solve your matching issue.  As to your second problem ... I'd kind of use a multi-dimensional array, but in either case, write a method which takes a `String` array (as the source) and a term to search for, that way you can just use `search(animal1, "dogs");` `search(animal2, "dogs");` ... etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multi dimensional array for your problem. And you can match the string values by "contains" and "toLowerCase" methods.

```
public class ChatBot {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] animalArray = new String[10][3];

    animalArray[0][0] = "Dogs";
    animalArray[0][1] = "Dawgs";

    animalArray[1][0] = "Cats";
    animalArray[1][1] = "Catds";

    animalArray[2][0] = "Horses";

    animalArray[3][0] = "Lamas";

    animalArray[4][0] = "Ducks";
    animalArray[4][1] = "Duckss";

    animalArray[5][0] = "Pigs";

    animalArray[6][0] = "Cows";

    animalArray[7][0] = "Rabbits";

    animalArray[8][0] = "Chickens";

    animalArray[9][0] = "Mice";


    String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hi there, theses are all the animals i like to talk about ! :"
            + "\n-Dogs" + "\n-Cats" + "\n-Rabbits" + "\n-Lamas" + "\n-Hores" + "\n-Ducks" + "\n-Pigs" + "\n-Cows"
            + "\n-Chickens" + "\n-Mice" + "\n-Ask me somthing !");

    while (true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < animalArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < animalArray[i].length; j++) {
                if (animalArray[i][j] != null && response.toLowerCase().contains(animalArray[i][j].toLowerCase())) {
                    String animal = animalArray[i][0];
                    response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(animal + " ? I love " + animal + ", they taste great!\n"
                            + "What other animals do you like ?");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    animalsDialog(arr(), start());
}
public static String start(){
    String res = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Dogs or Cats?");
    return res;
}
public static String[] arr(){
    String[] animals = new String[10];
    animals[0] = "Dogs";
    animals[1] = "dogs";
    animals[2] = "Cats";
    animals[3] = "cats";
    return animals;
}
public static void animalsDialog(String[] animals, String res){
    boolean search;
    String anim = "";
    for (String animal : animals) {
        search = animal.equalsIgnoreCase(res);
        if(search == true){
            anim = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You like " + animal + " Great!" + 
                    " What other animals do you like ?");
            animalsDialog(animals, anim);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this using only one array though ?

Comment: Also, it doesn't find the keyword in the inputdialog